# Почему append не работает для метода get(), а для setdefault() работает?

Tags: python, dict

Всех приветствую, возник вопрос и не нашел на него ответа. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в методе `get()` мы не можем добавлять, как и в методе `setdefault()` и в значениях `None`. Уже всё сломалось, похоже, мы создали пустой список в значениях частей примеров.

```
pets = {'Hatiko':('Parker', 'Wilson', 50),
        'Rusty':('Josh', 'King', 25),
        'Fido':('John', 'Smith', 28),
        'Rex':('Parker', 'Wilson', 50)
        }
        
result = {}
for val, key in pets.items():
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
print(result)

result1 = {}
for val, key in pets.items():
    result1[key] = result1.get(key, []) +[val]
print(result1)
```

Comment: Полагаю потому, что setdefault возвращает ссылку на объект а get копию объекта

Answer (score 2):

Давайте посмотрим помощь по этим методам через `help`:

> help(dict.setdefault)

```
setdefault(self, key, default=None, /)
    Insert key with a value of default if key is not in the dictionary.
    
    Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.
```

> help(dict.get)

```
get(self, key, default=None, /)
    Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.
```

Разница, как видно, в том, что `setdefault` **добавляет** пару `ключ: значение-по-умолчанию` в словарь, если ключ не найден в словаре, и уже после этого возвращает значение из словаря (теперь оно там есть). `get` добавление в словарь не делает, если ключ не найден, а просто возвращает `значение-по-умолчанию`.

Таким образом, если ранее ключа в словаре не было, в случае `setdefault` вам возвращается ссылка на элемент словаря (которого ранее в нём не было, а теперь есть), а в случае `get` возвращается значение, не привязанное к словарю. Поэтому в первом случае добавляя что-то в список, вы получаете это добавление и в словаре, а во втором случае в словаре это обновление не отражается, его нужно туда записать в явном виде.